# How to use regex quantifiers * and + for SwiftLint custom rule

Tags: swift, static-analysis, swiftlint

I'm trying to write a custom rule for [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint). Following the directions in the readme, I've added the following to `.swiftlint.yml`:

```
custom_rules:
  multi_clause_guard:
    regex: 'guard .*,'
```

However, this regex is not matching any lines in my project, despite there being plenty of lines where it should match, for example:

```
guard let x = Int(s), let y = Int(t) else { return }
```

I've tried various other values for the regex, and it works *until* you introduce a quantifier.

- ✅ `'guard .,'` will match the line `guard a,`
- ✅ `'guard ..,'` will match the line `guard _a,`
- ❌ `'guard .*,'` will not match the line `guard a,`
- ❌ `'guard .+,'` will not match the line `guard a,`

Is there a way I can use `*` and `+` in a SwiftLint custom rule?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that quantifiers can be applied to character sets that you define explicitly. In this case, it was enough for me to replace `.` with `[\h\S]` (which includes horizontal whitespace characters and any other character that's not a whitespace character).

```
custom_rules:
  multi_clause_guard:
    regex: 'guard [\h\S]*,'
```

If anyone knows how to make quantifiers work with `.`, I'm still interested to know!

Comment: OMG, I wish I had google this earlier. It cost me 3 hours to try and error.